# Storing some text from a buffer into a variable

Tags: buffers, variables, string, kill-ring

What is the "standard" way to store some text obtained from a buffer into a variable?

The only way I could think of was to use something along the lines of `(let ((beg (point))) (end-of-line) (copy-region-as-kill beg (point)))` and then store it with something like `(setq var1 (car kill-ring))`.

That feels somehow "hacky" and I was wondering if there is another function to do this, that I overlooked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Buffer Contents`

In short, use one of the following:

- `buffer-string`
- `buffer-substring`
- `buffer-substring-no-properties`